# Selenium Error: BadStatusLine

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Hi I am new in Selenium Webdriver and I am currently creating a test case for a specific function.

I have a current test case that is already working for another function, but when I include a new test case and run it. I receive an error: `BadStatusLine`.

Also when I run the individual test case it work perfectly fine, but when I run the whole test I will receive an error: `BadStatusLine`.

```
ERROR: test_task_xml (__main__.TestActuserLayouts)
Test if the task xml is hidden
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "acttemplate_layouts.py", line 25, in setUp
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").submit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 84, in submit
    self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 426, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

This is the whole test:

```
    import unittest


from selenium import webdriver



class TestActuserLayouts(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test user functions """
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    base_url = "http://samplepage.com"


    def setUp(self):
        """Base setting before test
        """
        driver = self.driver
        # Login
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_name("user_name").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("user_name").send_keys("userme")
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123")
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").submit()
        self.assertEqual(self.base_url + "/userme/inbox/", driver.current_url)

    def test_task_xml(self):
        """Test if the task xml is hidden
        """
        driver = self.driver
        # Get page by URL
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/userme/mission/")
        # Get page by URL
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/mission/update/0000000a-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/")
        self.assertEqual(self.base_url + "/mission/update/0000000a-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/", driver.current_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id("discussion-btn").click()
        # Scan browser if Task xml is not present
        self.assertFalse('Task xml' in self.driver.page_source)

    def test_task_list(self):
        """Test if the number of task for each mission is null
        """
        driver = self.driver
        #Get page url
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/userme/mission/")
        #Get page url
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/acttemplate/list-all/")
        #Scan browser if the number of task is null
        self.assertEqual(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[3]/td[4]").text != "", True)


    def tearDown(self):
        """Clear setting after test
        """
        self.driver.close()



# Run unit test directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

While the other test case is a failure. So, I am not really familiar with selenium and I need help to locate this error. Can someone please help me in this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the complete test.

Comment: Did you fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'll make a guess. Somehow, browser dies while you perform such actions like pressing buttons, clicking.

It's an error raised by httplib (low-level python http library), means that server inside browser didn't responded any of known http status codes (200, 300, 500, etc.), and instead, the response was '' (empty string).